# Convert Visual Basics Byte to PHP format

Tags: php, vb.net

I am having a problem where I have the full source of a VB program which sends signal to a RFID reader in a byte format. Now I want to convert that program into a web based system. The problem now is I dont know how to convert VB Byte into a php format. Are there any functions to do this?

This is my current VB code which sends command to the RFID reader in a byte format:

```
Private Sub Send_cmd()
    Dim Data() As Byte = {&H2, &H5, &H12, &HE6, &HA3}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While i < 5
        SerialPort1.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

This is the current php code we tried to execute:

```
$bbserialport = dio_open($portname, O_RDWR);

$data = "00000010 00000010 00000010 00000010 00000010 ";
$bytesent = dio_write($bbserialport, $data);
echoFlush("$data");
echoFlush("$bytesent");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, `dio_write()` expects `$data` as [a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dio-write.php), so you can just use an ad-hoc string and use the `\xhh` [escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) as follows:

```
$data = "\x02\x05\x12\xE6\xA3";
dio_write($bbserialport, $data);
```

However, you can also use a byte array:

```
$data=array(0x02, 0x05, 0x12, 0xE6, 0xA3);
foreach($data as $byte){
    dio_write(chr($byte));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about PHP

But your VB HEX Values are not the same as your PHP binary values

You are sending the SAME byte data 5 times

You are sending &H2 5 times where-as you should be sending....

00000010 00000101 00010010 11100110 10100011

&H2 is 00000010

&H5 is 00000101

&H12 is 00010010

&HE6 is 11100110

&HA3 is 10100011